# merge array object with three keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

There are two arrays of objects, a and b. Key is 'id' ,'isfix' ,'groupid'.

For example

```
a.id === b.id && a.isfix === b.isfix &&  a.groupid===b.groupdid
```

The sequence array is not the same.

I expected c.

I hope you don't use lodash. I like es6 or vanila js. thanks..

I think reduce and map and filter.. but Not as well as I thought.
I think make function...
input is a,b and output is c

```
var a = [
  {
    id:"555",
    groupID:"10",
    isFix:false,
    tolerancePlus:5,
    toleranceMinus:3
  },
  {
    id:"123",
    groupID:"10",
    isFix:true,
    tolerancePlus:"",
    toleranceMinus:7
  },
  {
    id:"555",
    groupID:"10",
    isFix:true,
    tolerancePlus:11,
    toleranceMinus:6
  }
]
```

---

```
var b =  [
  {
    id:"123",
    groupID:"10",
    isFix:true,
    tolerance:{
      min: null,
      plus : null
    }
  },
  {
    id:"555",
    groupID:"10",
    isFix:false,
    tolerance:{
      min: null,
      plus : null
    }
  },
  {
    id:"555",
    groupID:"10",
    isFix:true,
    tolerance:{
      min: null,
      plus : null
    }
  },
]
```

---

```
var c =  [
  {
    id:"123",
    groupID:"10",
    isFix:true,
    tolerance:{
      min: 7,
      plus : 0 // if "" that value is 0
    }
  },
  {
    id:"555",
    groupID:"10",
    isFix:false,
    tolerance:{
      min: 3,
      plus : 5
    }
  },
  {
    id:"555",
    groupID:"10",
    isFix:true,
    tolerance:{
      min: 6,
      plus : 11
    }
  },
]
```

Comment: Sorry, but your english is not clear. It's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Better now?

Comment: Here is a start: `b.find(x => x.id === a.id)`

Answer (score 0):

here's a way to do it :

it uses :

- [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [the `~` (bitwise not) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT)

**disclaimer** : since it uses the `~` operator, it can (and will) break if your tolerance are not 32-bit integers (it's undefined behavior AFAIR)

```js
// create your arrays
var a = [{id:"555",groupID:"10",isFix:false,tolerancePlus:5,toleranceMinus:3},{id:"123",groupID:"10",isFix:true,tolerancePlus:"",toleranceMinus:7},{id:"555",groupID:"10",isFix:true,tolerancePlus:11,toleranceMinus:6}]

var b =  [{id:"123",groupID:"10",isFix:true,tolerance:{min: null,plus : null}},{id:"555",groupID:"10",isFix:false,tolerance:{min: null,plus : null}},{id:"555",groupID:"10",isFix:true,tolerance:{min: null,plus : null}},]

// loop over b, creating a new array
let c = b.reduce((acc, value) => {
  
// find an object from a which correspond to the current object
  let linked = a.find(val => val.id === value.id && value.groupID === val.groupID && val.isFix === value.isFix)
  
// if it exists push it in the new array
  if(linked) {
    acc.push({
      id: linked.id,
      groupID: linked.groupID,
      isFix: linked.isFix,
      tolerance:{
        min: ~~linked.toleranceMinus, // the ~~value here use some magic to transform
        plus : ~~linked.tolerancePlus // everything that's not a number to 0
      }
    })
  }
  return acc
  
}, [])

console.log(c)

var wantedC =  [{id:"123",groupID:"10",isFix:true,tolerance:{min: 7,plus : 0}},{id:"555",groupID:"10",isFix:false,tolerance:{min: 3,plus : 5}},{id:"555",groupID:"10",isFix:true,tolerance:{min: 6,plus : 11}}]

console.log(JSON.stringify(wantedC) === JSON.stringify(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Logic in vanilla JS:

```js
var a = [
  {
    id: '555',
    groupID: '10',
    isFix: false,
    tolerancePlus: 5,
    toleranceMinus: 3
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    groupID: '10',
    isFix: true,
    tolerancePlus: '',
    toleranceMinus: 7
  },
  {
    id: '555',
    groupID: '10',
    isFix: true,
    tolerancePlus: 11,
    toleranceMinus: 6
  }
]
var b = [
  {
    id: '123',
    groupID: '10',
    isFix: true,
    tolerance: {
      min: null,
      plus: null
    }
  },
  {
    id: '555',
    groupID: '10',
    isFix: false,
    tolerance: {
      min: null,
      plus: null
    }
  },
  {
    id: '555',
    groupID: '10',
    isFix: true,
    tolerance: {
      min: null,
      plus: null
    }
  }
]

var c = a.map(data1 => {
  const toleranceData = b.map(data2 => {
    if (
      data1.id === data2.id &&
      data1.isfix === data2.isfix &&
      data1.groupdid === data2.groupdid
    ) {
      return {
        tolerance: {
          min: data1.toleranceMinus || 0,
          plus: data1.tolerancePlus || 0
        }
      }
    }
  })
  const { tolerance } = toleranceData.filter(d => d)[0]
  const { id, groupID, isFix } = data1
  return { id, groupID, isFix, tolerance }
})

console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

So we have 2 arrays of objects:

And we have a statement `a.id === b.id && a.isFix === b.isFix &&  a.groupid===b.groupdid`

To get what you need you can use `arr.find()` inside a `arr.map()` method and make our changes:

```js
const a = [{ id: "555", groupID: "10", isFix: false, tolerancePlus: 5, toleranceMinus: 3 }, { id: "123", groupID: "10", isFix: true, tolerancePlus: "", toleranceMinus: 7 }, { id: "555", groupID: "10", isFix: true, tolerancePlus: 11, toleranceMinus: 6 } ] 
const b = [{ id: "123", groupID: "10", isFix: true, tolerance: { min: null, plus: null } }, { id: "555", groupID: "10", isFix: false, tolerance: { min: null, plus: null } }, { id: "555", groupID: "10", isFix: true, tolerance: { min: null, plus: null } }, ]

let c = b.map(obj => {
  const valuesObj = a.find(item => item.id === obj.id && item.isFix === obj.isFix && item.groupid === obj.groupdid);
  if (valuesObj) {
    obj.tolerance.min = valuesObj.toleranceMinus || 0;
    obj.tolerance.plus = valuesObj.tolerancePlus || 0;
  }
  return obj;
})
console.log(c);
```